Classification of Platonic solids without presupposing convexity or global symmetries
This question grew from a possible misunderstanding of the definition of Platonic solids in this MSE post. In the question, I went out of my way to exclude convexity and global symmetries from the definition of Platonic solids (I was told this is non-standard). Despite being corrected, I have come to suspect these two properties are not needed as far as the classification of Platonic solids goes. However, I and others had little success (see the replies and comments in the cited MSE post for a view of some failed attempts).
I define Platonic solids by the following properties:

1A. The polyhedron is homeomorphic to $S^{2}$.
2A. No self-intersections.
3A. Each vertex is locally congruent in the following sense: If you take an open ball centered at a vertex, intersect it with the
polyhedron, the results will be identical up to isometries.
4A. All faces are regular polygons congruent to each other.
5A. The polyhedron is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Can we prove that any polyhedron satisfying properties #1A-#5A is necessarily one of the five Platonic solids (in the standard sense)? Keep in mind, we cannot presuppose global symmetries or convexity without proving them first.

My Progress.
By algebraic topological arguments and property #1A, we obtain $V-E+F=2$. Some combinatorial arguments then show that $(V, E, F)$ must be one of
$$ (4,6,4), (8,12,6), (6,12,8), (20,30,12), (12,30,20). $$
For polyhedra having the first, second, or fourth tuple, we may deduce that each vertex has precisely three edges attached to the vertex. This means for those shapes, each vertex has exactly three faces joining the vertex. Given a regular polygonal face (triangle, square, or pentagon, respectively), there is only one way to glue three such faces to a vertex (so a vertex with three congruent faces is "rigid"). Those unique vertices turn out to be convex (that is, if you take a sufficiently small open ball centered at the vertex and intersect with the interior of the polyhedron, the resulting shape will be convex), and thus Cauchy's rigidity theorem applies. Therefore, any polyhedron satisfying properties #1A-#5A with $(V, E, F) = (4,6,4)$, $(8,12,6)$, $(20,30,12)$ is a standard tetrahedron, cube, and dodecahedron, respectively.
For polyhedra having the third tuple, we may deduce that each vertex has precisely four edges attached to the vertex. This means for those shapes, each vertex has exactly four faces joining the vertex. Such vertices are not rigid! However, if the four faces are congruent, there is no way to make the vertex non-convex. Thus, Cauchy's rigidity theorem applies again: Any polyhedron satisfying properties #1A-#5A with $(V, E, F) = (6,12,8)$ is a standard octahedron.
We are now left with $(V, E, F) = (12,30,20)$, which would correspond to the icosahedron. This is where I have been stuck. Unlike in previous cases, a vertex with five faces is not only non-rigid, but it can also be non-convex. So then what else is there left to do?
To make the point where I ended up more clear, and what I am left to do, I'll state the following:

1B. $(V, E, F) = (12, 30, 20)$.
2B. No self-intersections.
3B. Each vertex is locally congruent in the following sense: If you take an open ball centered at a vertex, intersect it with the polyhedron, the results will be identical up to isometries.
4B. All faces are regular polygons congruent to each other.
5B. The polyhedron is homeomorphic to $S^{2}$.
6B. The polyhedron is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Do properties #1B-#6B imply the polyhedron must be the standard icosahedron? Or does there exist some really subtle construction of a concave icosahedron that still satisfies #1B-#6B? I have both tried to prove the conjecture and I have searched extensively for a counterexample.
My remaining hurdle is to rule out the possibility of a polyhedron satisfying the above properties that has non-convex vertices. See this depiction of an example of what I mean by a non-convex vertex:


You can characterize the 5 Platonic polyhedra in a stronger way, in terms of their graphs: planar, connected, and regular (=faces with constant number of edges, vertices with constant degree).  After that, the metric realisation is also unique

If you exclude convexity in general, you would have to include the Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra at least within the set of to be found regulars. "At least" here means the still being subsumed requirement of boundedness. Else there would be even more to be found: the well-known total set of 48 regular polyhedra! - However your requirements 1A+2A are a bit more restrictive than that.

Are you assuming a Platonic "solid" is a subset of 3-dimensional euclidean space? This is not mentioned. In any case "self-intersections" have no meaning, given that the "solid" is homeomorphic to the 2-sphere.

@DanielAsimov Yes, I was taking all shapes to be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ without explicating that assumption. Thank you for pointing out this ambiguity. I will edit the post accordingly.

Have you tried reading Coxeter's Regular Polytopes?  I think he has a variety of arguments that fit your preconditions.

One cannot get uniqueness for the icosahedron from 1B–5B alone:   Assume some 1–12 numbering of the vertices, and let $F$ be the 20-element set of triples ${a,b,c}$ that describe a face of the icosahedron.  Now consider a regular 11-simplex $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{R}^{11}$.  This has 12 vertices, also numbered 1–12.  Then, in $\mathbb{R}^{11}$, fill in the 20 triangles (i.e., 2-simplices) that correspond to the 20 face triples in $F$.  The result is a polyhedral surface in $\mathbb{R}^{11}$ that has properties 1B–5B but is not congruent by rigid motion to the regular icosahedron in 3-space.

By rigidity of faces (regular polygons, 4A), vertex congruence (3A), homeomorphy to $S^2$ (1A, esp. boundedness), and no self intersections (2A) you surely not only can deduce 1B (i.e. $(V,E,F)=(20,30,12)$) for your remaining case, you moreover get that the faces shall be regular triangles and that there will be 5 such per vertex. - Thus you are left with the correct combinatorics for the icosahedron.
The remainder therefore would be geometric variations thereof, while insisting on rigidity of faces (4A) $and$ congruence of vertex figures (3A).
Having just the combinatorics of an icosahedron still leaves room for variations (Cf. this mso post of yours). However asking additionally for equal-sized edges (by 4A) disqualifies continuous motions. Thence only dimpling-in a single vertex would be possible any longer. (Dimpling-in multiple, non-neighbouring vertices already would yield intersections.) However, this still contradicts to your required congruence of vertex figures (3A). - Thence you are done.
--- rk

I'm not convinced by the last paragraph (maybe I don't grasp it). Why does asking additionally for equal sized-edges disqualify continuous motions? Moreover, how do we rule out the possibility of a shape in which vertices "make non-convex shapes" yet still satisfy the listed properties? For example, maybe there is an icosohedron with vertices that look like this: https://i.sstatic.net/pBoOED9f.png

Did you ever build an icosahedron from Geomag (magnetical sticks and steel balls for its vertices)? There is no flexibility left. You only could dimple in a single vertex. (Dimpling non-neighbouring ones already would amount in intersections.)

In fact it is the final keystone, which closes the so far still open net, which enforces the additional rigidity.

@Dr.RichardKlitzing - The physical inflexibility may be the case, but in terms of answering the original question, it would be good to have a purely mathematical argument for that.
